# Geometric Random Variable problem help.

Tags: probability, statistics

$X$ is a geometric random variable with $p = 0.1$. Find:
$$a. F_X(5)$$
$$b. Pr(5 < X \leq 11)$$
$$c. Pr(X=7|5<X\leq11)$$
$$d. E(X|3<X\leq11)$$
$$e. E(X^2|3<X\leq11)$$
$$f. Var(X|3<X\leq11)$$

a.$$F_X(5) = P(X\leq5)=1-(1-p)^x$$
$$=1-(0.9)^5$$
$$=0.40951$$

b. $$Pr(5<X\leq11)=F_X(11)-F_X(5)$$
$$=0.2766794039$$

c. Not too sure about this one.
$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$
$$Pr(X=7) = F_X(7) = 0.5217031$$
$$Pr(5<X\leq11)=0.2766794039$$
What do I do next?

d. Don't know how to do this one.
e. Don't know how to do this one.
f. Variance $= E[X^2]-E[X]^2$, so the answer would require d and e.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

c) $Pr(X=7)=F_X(7)-F_X(6)$

then compute $$Pr(X=7|5<X\leq 11) = \frac{Pr(X=7)}{Pr(5<X\leq 11)}$$

d) Compute $Pr(X=x|3<X \leq 11)$ where $ 3< x\leq 11$, then use \begin{align}\mathbb{E}[X|3<X\leq 11]&=\sum_{x=4}^{11}xPr(X=x|3<X\leq 11) \\&=\sum_{x=4}^{11}\frac{xPr(X=x)}{Pr(3<X\leq 11)}\\
&=\frac{1}{Pr(3<X\leq 11)}\sum_{x=4}^{11}x(1-p)^{x-1}p\\
&=\frac{p}{Pr(3<X\leq 11)}\sum_{x=4}^{11}x(1-p)^{x-1}\\\end{align}

Similarly for part e.

Comment: Why is Pr(X=7) = F(7)-F(6)? In my book, it says Pr(X=x) = F(x).

Comment: $F_X(x) = Pr(X \leq x) \neq Pr(X=x)$

Comment: I double checked the book and I read it incorrectly. Is Pr(X=x) = F(x) - F(x-1)?
Would the answer to c be: 0.192?

Comment: $Pr(X=x)=F(x)-F(x-1)$ because at this setting, $X$ takes integer value. and there is only one integer in $(x-1, x]$. hmm... I don't think the final answer matters that much for learning purposes. Focus on concept. =)

Comment: I understand that now, thank you!
For part d:
Is $$Pr(X=x|3<X\leq11) = Pr(3<X\leq11)$$? What is the significance of the X=x?

Comment: what is the probability that $X$ takes value $x$ given that we know $X$ is bigger than $3$ and at most $11$. $$Pr(X=x|3< X \leq 11) = \frac{Pr(X=x)}{Pr(3< X \leq 11) }$$

Comment: Don't really know how to answer that. Can you provide another hint?

Comment: Edited the answer, you can either evaluate directly or if you are familiar with calculus and geometric sum, you can do cooler stuff.

Comment: So Pr(X=x) is the PDF and Pr(3<X<=11) is F(11)-F(3). Thank you!

Comment: PMF is usually used for discrete random variable while pdf is usually used for continuous random variable.